# How to make sprite removed permanently in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

i have used linkedlist to make the sprite display in cocos2d-android game app, if the sprite is destroyed it should get permanently destroyed and get removed, but this sprite disappears and again appears, dont know how to remove the sprite permanently, any helps?
This is the code for delete.

```
for (CCSprite ship2 : shipsToDelete)
    {
        _ships2.remove(ship2);
        removeChild(ship2, true);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> hashMap1;
LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> hashMap2 ;

for (Object key : hashMap1.keySet()) {
    hashMap2.remove(key);
}
```

---

```
 for (CCSprite ship2 : shipsToDelete){
     if(_ships2.contains(ship2){ 
      _ships2.remove(ship2);
      removeChild(ship2, true);
     }
 }
```

This will work only if `_ships2 = shipsToDelete;` 
   but the item from both _ships2 , shipsToDelete will be remove , i thing it wont enter to if clause when `_ships2 = shipsToDelete.clone()` , so you have to use liked hashmap or exact object reference

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have used like this protected LinkedList<CCSprite> _ships2; in cocos2d the default keyword for any object is CCSprite, so how will i used the above code? @Sandy09

Answer (score 0):

In the destructor Call function.

```
CC_SAFE_RELEASE(_object);
```